# Replacing a washer in a 3 knob tub faucet

Tags: faucet, bathtub

I have a leak from the hot handle of a 3 knob tub faucet when the water is running.  I am able to turn off the hot water because I have access to the hot water heater but I live in a condo that does not have a water shut off for just my unit.  I have to request the management company to shut off the water which affects several units.  There is also a charge for this request.

Can I replace the washer by just shutting off the hot water?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I replace the washer by just shutting off the hot water?

YES- on 3-handled tub/shower valve units the supply water is delivered seperately to the hot and cold sides; turning off the hot water supply will allow you to work on the hot side valve.

Because multiple units will be affected you should do some research on how these are repaired prior to turning the supply off, to minimize down time.

Your description of the problem ("leak from the hot **handle**... when the water is running") is indicative of a problem with the valve's *packing*. I recommend rebuilding the whole valve while you have the water turned off (bibb washer, packing, grease the stem thread, seat if necessay, etc.) Keep in mind that there are many (many, many, many) brands, models, and configurations out there and there are no "standard" parts. Washers come in a bunch of different sizes and types.